# How to get self-status of CustomCheckbox

Tags: angular

I have a custom angular checkbox, based on using the `ControlValueAccessor` interface.
This, on itself works well and the checkbox get's displayed as required.

What I would like to achieve is when the `@Input() showChanges: boolean = true` that the CSS gets adjusted to the display the box in a different color.

However, in the component -with the ControlValueAccessor- there is no property `.dirty` that is accessible? The idea would be that I can set the `showDirty` option externally and that the checkBox internals verifies if the status is indeed `dirty`

So in HTML where the component is used

```
<app-checkbox 
  [showDirty]="true"
  [formControl]="checkBox"></app-checkbox>
```

And subsequently in the `CheckBoxComponent`

```
@Input() showDirty: boolean = false; 

get dirty(): boolean {
    return (this.dirty && this.showDirty) //nothing available for 'this.dirty'?
}
```

But for some reason I do not have access to the `FormControl` interface?

I have tried by extending the `FormControl` class but that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

The `ControlValueAccessor` interface doesn't have the `dirty` property. See the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor).

```
interface ControlValueAccessor {
  writeValue(obj: any): void
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean)?: void
}
```

You can get the `dirty` property from the `FormControl`. And the `FormControl` will be created by the `FormGroup` and not by your custom control itself. So like this way:

```
const nameControl = this.myForm.get('name'); // or this.myForm.controls['name'];
if (nameControl.dirty) {
  // ...
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-input-controlvalueaccessor-uvg4ck?file=src/app/app.component.ts) is a Stackblitz example.

Comment: Hi Flo, I understand that I can get the `dirty` property from the `FormGroup` that is not the issue, nor is it what I asked. The CustomControl has an internal SCSS that determines how the checkbox input is displayed. This is an enclosed scope and not accessible from the outside (i.e. the internal SCSS of the control, cannot be accessed by the `FormGroup` or its parent component. Hence the requirement to get the `dirty` property of the CustomControl

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: [by RITCHIE JACOBS](https://ritchiejacobs.be/angular-custom-form-component)

Solution:

- remove any `provider' entries
- add the constructor as below

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Self, Optional } from "@angular/core";
import { ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NgControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

@Component({
  selector: "fl-checkbox",
  templateUrl: "./fl-checkbox.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./fl-checkbox.component.scss"],
})
export class CustomCheckboxComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
  
  fc!: FormControl
  uid: string = uuidv4()
  @Input() disabled: boolean = false;
  @Input() checked: boolean = false;
  @Input() showDirty: boolean = false; 

  constructor(
    @Self()
    @Optional()
    private ngControl: NgControl
  ) {
    if (this.ngControl) {
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }

  onChange: any = () => {};
  onTouched: any = () => {};
  
  writeValue(checked: boolean): void {
    this.checked = checked;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  } 

  get dirty(): boolean {
    const _dirty = <boolean>this.ngControl?.dirty;
    return (_dirty && this.showDirty);
  }
  
  onModelChange(e: boolean) {
    this.checked = e;

    this.onChange(e);
    this.onTouched();
  }
}
```